# Overwriting Magento error messages

Tags: javascript

is it possible to override Magento `addError($this->__());` with prototype javascript?

My plan is to create validation before the user clicks the submit button for the re-captcher form. this is what i'm trying to override:

```
catch (Exception $e) {
        if (strlen($e->getMessage()) > 0) {
         $session =  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__($e->getMessage()));
            $e =  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setFormData($post);
            $e->addSuccess($session);
        }
        if ($redirectUrl = Mage::getSingleton('review/session')->getRedirectUrl(true)) {
            $this->_redirectUrl($redirectUrl);
            return;
        }
        $this->_redirectReferer();
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to overwrite PHP with Javascript since PHP is processed server side and Javascript client side.

However Javascript will be executed first before you send the request of to be processed by php so you can write your own Magento validation script using [this article](http://magento-quickies.tumblr.com/post/6579512188/magento-custom-form-validation).

To prevent or modify the behaviour of the php script you've posted in your question you will need to overwrite the controller or model that it is in. To learn more about that please reference [this Inchoo post](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/)